# Verify the UserID, Forgot question and Forgot Answer in ASP.net Membership

Tags: asp.net

I am having an ASP.net page with userid and question and answer

I need to verify the userid, answer is correct or not

I no need to enablepasswordretrival

and my password is hashed

how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the ASP.NET membership provider? If so then the system will do that authentication for you, you just need to set the appropriate permissions in each folder's web.config in your web site. Just make sure that the folder containing the login form, registration form, etc (all the content that anonymous users can get to, and yes, login needs that as they are anonymous until they have actually logged in) is set to allow anonymous users.

You can't have password retrieval with hashed passwords as it's a trapdoor (i.e. one way) encryption and can't be reversed. The only option with hashed passwords is to issue a new password.